# Ubuntu Software application empty on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

The Ubuntu Software application shows only an empty screen in the Explore tab, and the same in Installed screen. How can I fix it so that I can install Tweaks?

Comment: Try to restart it with `snap-store --quit` then re-launch it. It has a tendency to take a long time first run, but killing it and restarting then waiting usually is enough to wake it up.

Comment: snap-store --quit worked perfectly.  Thanks

Comment: Same for me thank you very much for snap-store --quit